# E2015 Ambiguity between __fastcall IdGlobal::Sleep(unsigned int) and __stdcall Sleep(unsigned long)

Tags: c++builder

I have a couple of problems compiling a very old application developed using C++ Builder 6 Pro. Both are in the same code block I copied above.

1. E2015 Ambiguity between __fastcall IdGlobal::Sleep(unsigned int) and __stdcall Sleep(unsigned long)
2. undefined exception (I mean exception in catch(Exception &exception). I hope this is caused by the error about Sleep...

So, I do not know where Sleep comes from but I think I did not want to use IdGlobal::Sleep(), how can I specify I want the 2nd Sleep?

```
   try
   {
      Wp->Open = true;
      Sleep(1500);
   }
   catch(Exception &exception)
   {
      TLogSysInstance->Write(_FILE("TFormMain", "PresetterInit()" + exception.Message));
      if(Wp->Open != true)
      {
         Application->MessageBox("La porta di comunicazione selezionata per il PRESETTER non si apre.\n"
            "Verificare il setup della porta di comunicazione nel file APP.INI.\n"
            "E' probabile che debba essere cambiata la porta di comunicazione selezionata.",
            "Attenzione: errore aprendo la porta di comunicazione", MB_OK + MB_ICONWARNING);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IdGlobal` is a unit in the Indy package. It has its own `Sleep()` function declared in `IdGlobal.hpp` in the `Idglobal` namespace.

The Win32 API also has its own `Sleep()` function declared in the global namespace.

Since you are not qualifying which namespace you want to use `Sleep()` from, the compiler has to search the namespaces that are currently available to it, and it is finding 2 different `Sleep()`'s that can both accept an integer argument. It doesn't know which one to use, so it aborts the compilation.

The only way you can get this error is if the code shown has both `#include <windows.h>` and `#include <IdGlobal.hpp>` statements (directly or indirectly), and a `using namespace Idglobal;` statement (such as the one at the bottom of `IdGlobal.hpp`).

The easiest way to fix this is to simply qualify the namespace you want to use `Sleep()` from, eg: `::Sleep(1500);` for the Win32 function.

Otherwise, you could try reorganizing the code in question so it is not located in a translation unit that uses Indy, thus doesn't need `IdGlobal.hpp`.

Otherwise, you can define the `NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE` conditional (renamed to `DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE` in later C++Builder versions) in your project settings, or at least above `#include <IdGlobal.hpp>`. This will prevent any Delphi-generated `.hpp` file (including `IdGlobal.hpp`) from dumping its content into the global namespace. This *may* have unwanted side effects for the rest of the VCL though, so use this carefully. In later versions of C++Builder, you could instead define `NO_USING_NAMESPACE_IDGLOBAL` to isolate just `IdGlobal.hpp` without affecting other headers. But that is not an option in BCB6.

Comment: Thanks Remy, this solves the problem. In the mean time another question arised... is there a way in BCB 6 to build a project only with the packages and libraries it really uses? In the bpr file I see a lot of libs and packages not used in the application, seems it is a list of every package and library installed in BCB 6.

Comment: @MassimoManca You generally don't need to worry about that, the linker will ignore any packages that are not actually being used by the compiled code. But yes, there is a way to slim down the project. You could simply remove the package references and let the IDE prompt you to re-add the ones it actually needs. In the long term, I would suggest unloading any project from the IDE, then disable (not remove) all installed packages, which will save as the default settings, and then when creating new projects you can re-enable only the packages you need.

Comment: if I disable a package C++ Builder crashes. It is running on a WinXP SP3 VM (virtual box) on a Win7 host. May I just edit the .bpr removing all the packages and libraries and then build it adding the missing packages and libraries?